# Proving that $\log x$ is big $O$ of $x^k$ for every positive $k$

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-complexity

Can I know a way to prove the above condition purely by the definition (and may be Taylor Series) and without using De l'Hôpital's rule? It is obvious for $k$ greater than or equal to $1$ but how can you show for $k$ is less than $1$?

Comment: If you know that $\log x=O(x)$, use $\log x=\frac1k\log (x^k)$ to deduce that $\log x=O(x^k)$ for every positive $k$.

Comment: To begin with, what is your definition of the logarithm ?

Answer (score 0):

It is $O(x^k)$ because it is $o(x^k)$ for any $k>0$. This results from the basic high school limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x}=0$$
and the functional properties of the logarithm.

Comment: Another unexplained anonymous downvote…

Comment: I did not downvote it. But the answer is not exactly helpful. You do not say how to prove the case $k=1$, nor how to show that the general case follows from it.

Comment: I did not say how to prove the basic case, because it proved in high school, and the question is not from someone in high school. Further, usually, I prefer to give hints rather than full solutions – it's more educational.

Comment: One can hypothetize that this answer is not useful to anybody asking the question. In particular, the trick showing that the $k=1$ case implies the case of every $k>0$ is not explained.

Comment: What do you think `the functional properties of log` mean?

Comment: What does this part mean, you ask? A.: A hint only useful to somebody who already knows how to solve this mathematical question. (That is, if the question in your comment is addressed at me, but then I fail to understand why you omit @.)